# Kafka and Zookeeper not working give an error (Kafka shutting down and INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled despite enabling it)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am a beginner and I have to use Kafka for data transfer into/from Hadoop FS (or any other application, not just through `put` or `copyFromLocal` commands),kafka needs zookeeper as well, I enabled Zooekeeper audit logging but I still get errors.

For Kafka, when I want to start it:

```
JMX_PORT=8004 bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

I get the error:

```
[2022-02-16 13:56:45,939] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-02-16 13:56:46,114] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-02-16 13:56:46,133] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-02-16 13:56:46,133] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
[2022-02-16 13:56:46,165] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

And when I want to start Zookeeper using the command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

I get the following (and it gets stuck on it):

```
[2022-02-16 14:03:13,954] INFO zookeeper.request_throttler.shutdownTimeout = 10000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.RequestThrottler)
[2022-02-16 14:03:13,955] INFO PrepRequestProcessor (sid:0) started, reconfigEnabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2022-02-16 14:03:14,136] INFO Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 maxNeverUsedIntervalMs=0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ContainerManager)
[2022-02-16 14:03:14,138] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
```

Does anyone know how to work this out? I enabled audit logging but still. Same problem.

Comment: Please include logs before `INFO shutting down`

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper CLI isn't "stuck"; it's waiting for connections.

Open a new terminal and start Kafka

Alternatively, you could use Docker Compose / Kubernetes, if you think your host / local JVM is causing issues